# Identifying the recycle bin mail folder in C# with the Graph-API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

using the C# Graph-API I am trying to find the recycle bin folder of a user.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
However the attribute "wellKnownName" seems to be (no longer?!) present, and I can't find any other RELIABLE indicator (the name is not necessarily unique; and localization is an issue if one would approach it this way).

Any ideas or properties I have missed?

Comment: The example response in the article you linked contains a "Deleted Items" folder.

Comment: How do you identify it for all possible language settings then?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is still faulty as mentioned before in:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4922